# VueJS: Bind div content to iframe src

Tags: javascript, iframe, vue.js

I have this pdf embedded on my Vue file, but I want to get the content from a div where I define the html table:

```
<template>
  <div id="editor"> HTML TABLE HERE </div>
  <iframe :src="iframe.src" type="application/pdf" width="100%" 
    height="650" frameborder="0" style="position:relative;z 
    index:999" ref="frame" @load="load" v-show="iframe.loaded">
  </iframe>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        iframe: {
          src: '', //DIV HERE #EDITOR
          loaded: false
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      load: function(){
        this.iframe.loaded = true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible! The iframe's `src` attribute takes in a URL address and will try to load the whole page. So, instead of trying to pass it any kind of reference to the editor div, pass it the current URL via `window.location.href`.

Then, by setting a `ref` attribute on the editor div, you can reference it in your `mounted` lifecycle hook and get it's position and dimension. Once you have that, you can style the iframe and a wrapper div to only show contents of the `editor.

Here's the whole thing (and a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyWrOr)):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="editor" ref="editor">HTML TABLE HERE</div>
    <div 
      id="iframe-wrapper"
      :style="iframe.wrapperStyle" 
    >
      <iframe 
        v-if="loaded"
        :src="iframe.src"
        :style="iframe.style"
        :height="iframe.style.height"
        :width="iframe.style.width"
        type="application/pdf"
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      iframe: {
        src: window.location.href,
        style: null,
        wrapperStyle: null,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let editor = this.$refs.editor;
    this.iframe.style = {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      top: -editor.offsetTop + "px",
      left: -editor.offsetLeft + "px",
    }    
    this.iframe.wrapperStyle = {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      height: editor.clientHeight + "px",
      width: editor.clientWidth + "px",
    } 
    this.loaded = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When testing the codepen on Chrome `Version 66.0.3359.139`, there is a CORS error and it does not load. `Access to Font at 'https://static.codepen.io/assets/telefon/bold/af889c53-1ee3-4868-8fdc-2b310d587b50-3-b7a87e0fbd213943fae0c0ef5985635dd43fa9c24876b2725127a13ccaf4ab6a.woff' from origin 'https://codepen.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.`